# How to cure a curse in Thea 2: The Shattering?

Tags: thea2-the-shattering

Our village got a curse/illness, and our healers don't know how to heal it.

Is there a way to heal curses?

We're willing to share our fruits and cakes with anyone willing,

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What kind of illness? I found sickness, light-sick, mental damage and mystical damage...

Comment: its a curse/illness for an event encountered, i found out a bit of info - like building a herb-building will cure it faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Steam community](https://steamcommunity.com/app/606230/discussions/0/1745605598701542188/):

> Visit another village (such as Slavyans), and choose the option to stay and rest.
> It won't always show up, but there's a chance for a healer (Witch) to be in town who will help you remove curses.

> If you have a Witch in your own party, you'll have the option to cure all curses in your entire party for free. If you do not, depending on the type of curse being removed (and the village you're visiting), you'll either need to trade items (sometimes gems), or some of your party will need to give blood (meaning, they take health damage). The curses will be removed however.

> Again, if you have a Witch in your own party when you do this, it will remove ALL curses (mental, physical, and spiritual). If you do not, it will only remove one type per visit, and the curse healer is not always there.

There should be also a curse removal Ritual as well, but [people are complaining](https://steamcommunity.com/app/606230/discussions/0/1798529872645375344/) that is inefficient and expensive.

Comment: TY, indeed I tried the 'curse removal Ritual' - and it didn't work, that's the reason I asked.

Comment: @ShloEmi yes, and you have to try it more than once. That's why people are complaining about it...